# loop through a matrix using map() python

Tags: python, for-loop, map-function

I want to loop through a matrix and compare each element in the row with the rest values of the row (itself) without using for loop :)

for example:
x= [[1,3], [4,5]]

if the number x[i][j] is < than x[i][j+1] then return the index of x[i][j] in a new list.

for example:
x= [[1,3], [4,5]] I need the output to be the B=[0,0] where the 0,0 is the index position of the less values
as 1 < 3 in the first row
and 4 <5 in the second row

:) thank you so much

```
import numpy as np

def max_comp(row):
    return np.where(row>=max(row), True, False)

matrix = np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5))
output = np.apply_along_axis(max_comp, axis=1, arr=matrix)
print(matrix)
print(output
```

I tried to change the max_comp() to :
def max_comp(row):
return np.where(row < row+1, row, 0)

but it dose not give me the index of the true values

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: @FrankYellin I updated the question, hope its clear this time :(